# How to store how many times user logged in?

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Model**

```
function Updateno($user,$data){
       $this->db->where('username', $user);  
        $this->db->update('user', $data);
    }
```

**Controller**

```
//user login function
    function Ulogin(){

        if($this->session->userdata('user'))
        {
             $data['user'] = $this->session->userdata('user');
            $this->load->view("User/choosecategory",$data);
        }
        else
        {        
        $data = array(
        'username' =>$this->input->post('username'),
        'password' =>$this->input->post('password'),
        );
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','UserName','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required');
        if($this->form_validation->run()==false)
            {
            $this->load->view('User/login');
            }
        else
            {
            if($this->user_model->userlogin($data)==false)
            {
                $data['error'] = '<div class="alert alert-danger text-danger">Please Provide Valid Username/Password!</div>';
            $this->load->view('User/login',$data);
            }
            else
            {
               $this->session->set_userdata('user',$data['username']);
                $data['user'] = $this->session->userdata('user');
                $counter = array(
        'logged_in' =>'logged_in'+1
        ); 
        $this->user_model->Updateno($this->session->userdata('user'),$counter);
               $this->load->view("User/choosecategory",$data);
            }
            }
        }
    }
```

**I want whenever user login successfully my logged_in cloumn value increase by 1 but in this code  the value of logged_in column always to 1,plz help me anyone here**

Comment: i give it in array like        $counter = array(
        'logged_in' =>'logged_in'+1
        );  in controller in last check

Comment: Use `echo $this->db->last_query();` to print update query and check what it return

Comment: And change your array to `$counter = array(
        'logged_in' =>"'logged_in'+1"
        ); `

Comment: its not working,this chage the value 1 to 0

Comment: @John Conde i understand his problem, He wrote this code on his own, he tried to increment the value - but failed - and he asked for help in this specific matter. i don't even know what's missing here - beside the fact that the post could've a better structure

Comment: What this return `echo $this->db->last_query();`?? Paste your query

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure you ***[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the only thing you need to do here is to increment the value by 1

try the following piece of code

your model

```
function Updateno($user)
{
    $this->db->where('username', $user); 
    $this->db->set("logged_in","logged_in+1",false);
    $this->db->update('user');
}
```

and in your controller

```
$this->user_model->Updateno($this->session->userdata('user'));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is this:

```
$value = explode("logged_in", $counter['logged_in']); //get the number of the counter
$counter['logged_in'] = 'logged_in' . ((int)$value[1] +1); //increase value by 1
```

This will get the current counter value from your string and increase it by 1

I made a demo to show how you can use it

**DEMO:** https://eval.in/773121

Comment: the value is stored in a db !

Comment: @sintakonte I guess i missread the problem. I've changed my answer, though your answer seems cleaner anyways